# Why generate deadlock when subquery select the same table in mysql?

Tags: mysql, transactions, deadlock

I found a very interesting thing, a dead lock was found as below:

LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK

Transation (1):

`UPDATE A set value = 1 where id = 1;`

> (1) Waiting for table A X Lock:
>   RECORD LOCKS space id 1174 page no 3 n
>   bits 120 index PRIMARY of table test.A trx id
>   524946 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
>   Record lock, heap no
>   28 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 16; compact format; info bits 0

Transation (2):

```
UPDATE B INNER JOIN (  
     SELECT A.id, A.value AS value1, IFNULL(t.value, 0) AS value2  
     FROM A  
     LEFT JOIN (  
       SELECT SUM(c.value) AS value  
       FROM C  
       INNER JOIN A ON C.a_id = A.id  
       GROUP BY C.a_id  
     )
  ) t SET B.value = t.value1 + t.value2
```

> (1) Hold table A S Lock;
>   RECORD LOCKS space id 1174 page no 3 n bits 120 index PRIMARY of table test.A trx id 281479462315824 lock mode S locks rec but not gap
>   Record lock, heap no 2 PHYSICAL RECORD:
>   n_fields 16; compact format; info bits 0
>
> (2) Waiting for table A S Lock;
>    RECORD LOCKS space id 1174 page no 3 n bits 120 index PRIMARY of table lancai_u.finance_user trx id 281479462315824 lock mode S waiting
>   Record lock, heap no 28 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 16; compact format; info bits 0